# Node - Bitwise Calculations with IP Addresses

Tags: javascript, node.js, bit-manipulation

I've made a DNS tool in Node and I would like to know how I can optimize the performance of `toLong()` using bitwise? I've included some of my pseudo-code for reference.

```
var _parser = function (ip) {
  return ip.split('.').map(function (i) {
    return i | 0;
  });
},

_isIPv4 = function (ip) {
  var i, isValid = true, octets = _parser(ip);

  if (octets.length !== 4) {
    isValid = false;
  }
  octets.forEach(function (octet) {
    if (octet < 0 || octet > 255) {
      isValid = false;
    }
  });
  return isValid;
};

toLong: function (ip) {
  var i, converted, octets = _parser(ip);

  if (!_isIPv4(ip)) {
    throw 'Invalid IPv4 address!';
  }
  converted = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < octets.length; i++) {
    converted += octets[i] * Math.pow(256, (3 - i));
  }
  return converted;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd really recommend unrolling those loops and ditching the function calls. I added a revision to the jsPerf created by @imsky: http://jsperf.com/node-bitwise-calculations-with-ip-addresses/6 Looks like this is ~5x faster than the original.

```
var unrolledLong = function(ip) {
  var octets = ip.split('.');
  if (octets.length !== 4) throw "Invalid IPv4 address!";

  octets[0] = octets[0] | 0;
  octets[1] = octets[1] | 0;
  octets[2] = octets[2] | 0;
  octets[3] = octets[3] | 0;

  if ((octets[0] < 0 || octets[0] > 255) ||
      (octets[1] < 0 || octets[1] > 255) ||
      (octets[2] < 0 || octets[2] > 255) ||
      (octets[3] < 0 || octets[3] > 255)) {
    throw 'Invalid IPv4 address!';
  }
  // The >>> 0 calls will force the number back to an unsigned value.
  return octets[3] +
    ((octets[2] << 8) >>> 0) +
    ((octets[1] << 16) >>> 0) +
    ((octets[0] << 24) >>> 0);
};
```

If that bitwise math is a little weird, you can also use multiplication:

```
var unrolledLong = function(ip) {
  var octets = ip.split('.');
  if (octets.length !== 4) throw "Invalid IPv4 address!";

  octets[0] = octets[0] | 0;
  octets[1] = octets[1] | 0;
  octets[2] = octets[2] | 0;
  octets[3] = octets[3] | 0;

  if ((octets[0] < 0 || octets[0] > 255) ||
      (octets[1] < 0 || octets[1] > 255) ||
      (octets[2] < 0 || octets[2] > 255) ||
      (octets[3] < 0 || octets[3] > 255)) {
    throw 'Invalid IPv4 address!';
  }
  // The >>> 0 calls will force the number back to an unsigned value.
  return octets[3] +
    (octets[2] * 0x100) +
    (octets[1] * 0x10000) +
    (octets[0] * 0x1000000);
};
```

Comment: I've got a lot of reading to do with bitwise. I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: I think the math is off. When given ```unrolledLong('172.2.6.139')``` It returns ```-1409153397```. This was the problem I ran into when trying to use bitwise. I'm thinking I might have to convert to binary first.

Comment: @TheGrayFox check my revised answer, I think it works as you expect.

Comment: @TheGrayFox Fixed mine too.

Comment: It took me some time to understand why unrolling would be faster. I guess because as a student in Software Development, the first thing you learn is to not repeat yourself and to write tests that are expected to fail and then re-iterate over it. I learned a lot from these benchmarks and found this great source: http://oreilly.com/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html

Comment: Yeah, the `for` loops might not be too bad, though they'd still cause a little branching. Depending on the engine, it might even automatically unroll them for you. The `.forEach` and `Math.pow` calls will definitely slow things down because they won't inline and the `.forEach` creates a new function scope.

Comment: Not using bitwise operations works just as fast with this variant, since the values never change: `return (octets[0] * 16777216) + (octets[1] * 65536) + (octets[2] * 256) + octets[3];` My answer and the jsPerf has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: `octets[0] |= 0` and `if( ( octets[0] & 0xFFFFFF00 ) ){` (or `& ~0xFF`), and you don't need the `>>>0` except on `octets[0]`.  And since we're using bitwise math, you might as well `|` the values instead of `+`'ing them.  And _please do not throw strings_

Comment: @imsky Yep, thats the same multiplication I have in my answer. :)

Comment: @loganfsmyth Yeah, caught that after I posted the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://jsperf.com/node-bitwise-calculations-with-ip-addresses

Edit 2: this was the original solution, around 2x performance:

```
var p256 = [Math.pow(256, 3), Math.pow(256, 2), 256, 1];
var cache = {};

var newToLongCache = function(ip) {
  var octets = _parser(ip);
  var converted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < octets.length; i++) {
    var val = octets[i];
    if (cache[val] == null) {
      cache[val] = {};
    }
    if (cache[val][i] == null) {
      cache[val][i] = val * p256[i];
    }
    converted += cache[val][i];
  }
  return converted;
};
```

This is the updated unrolled solution, without bitwise operators (same 5x performance):

```
 var unrolledMultiplicationLongNoBitwise = function(ip) {
      var octets = ip.split('.');
      if (octets.length !== 4) throw "Invalid IPv4 address!";

      octets[0] = octets[0] | 0;
      octets[1] = octets[1] | 0;
      octets[2] = octets[2] | 0;
      octets[3] = octets[3] | 0;

      if ((octets[0] < 0 || octets[0] > 255) ||
        (octets[1] < 0 || octets[1] > 255) ||
        (octets[2] < 0 || octets[2] > 255) ||
        (octets[3] < 0 || octets[3] > 255)) {
        throw 'Invalid IPv4 address!';
      }

      return (octets[0] * 16777216) + (octets[1] * 65536) +
      (octets[2] * 256) + octets[3];
    };
```

Comment: +1 for benchmarking. I'll take a look at what you did and come up with something. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just playing around with optimizing this:

```
function( ip ){
  var octets = ip.split( '.' );

  if( ( octets.length !== 4 )        ||
      ( ( octets[0] |= 0 ) & ~0xFF ) ||
      ( ( octets[1] |= 0 ) & ~0xFF ) ||
      ( ( octets[2] |= 0 ) & ~0xFF ) ||
      ( ( octets[3] |= 0 ) & ~0xFF ) ){
    throw new Error( 'Invalid IPv4 address!' );
  }

  return ( octets[3]       ) |
         ( octets[2] << 8  ) |
         ( octets[1] << 16 ) |
         ( octets[0] * 0x1000000 );
}
```